# how can I perform any task after uninstalling my apk?

Tags: android

I want to install the apk from internal/external memory after uninstalling the same apk.?(actually i want to update my apk,if i directly(don't uninstall the current apk) install my updated apk then there comes signature issue.)

```
final Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
if (isSDPresent) {
    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/sdcard1/Download/" + "Life.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
}else {
    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/" + "Life.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
}
installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(installIntent);
```

Comment: How do you achieve this (that gives you signature issue) -- show some code. And what is that signature issue?

Comment: I download the latest apk and store it into phone internal/external memory and after that i wirte this code

Comment: You should have edited your question instead of posting this as a comment: see how it's unreadable?

Comment: don't hard code path of external storage (SDCard) inside code. use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () instead

Comment: Just sign both app versions with identical keys. Don't install app from IDE 1st time because it will be signed with debug key and cause sign issue.

Comment: @shkschneider An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed.           This error I'm facing I don't uninstalled the current installed apk from device. Now main issue of mine is that if I uninstalled my current apk then how can I install my updated downloaded apk.

Comment: Of course you cannot replace a package with conflicting signatures. Why does that happen? It should have the same signature. If they differ, you're doomed.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you are seeing is by design.

Android does not allow any code within an APK to be run once the user chooses to remove it - there are no notifications and no pre-uninstall actions that you can use. It's designed that way to prevent developers from writing Apps that can never be uninstalled by the user.

Having two apps with the same package name but signed with different keys is also not allowed, and can only be resolved by the user manually removing the first app before installing the second. This is to prevent developers from writing Apps to imitate other Apps (like Facebook for example) without the user knowing about it.

Comment: Exactly, no solution out of this with conflicting signature. For obvious security reasons. OP should not have conflicting signatures in the first place.

Comment: does broadcast receiver or services help me in this?

Comment: No. There is no method (activities, services, broadcast receivers or otherwise) for this to happen on stock Android. If you want Android to behave like this, you need to build your own version.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your apk using below command that will upgrade application that is exactly same as when you perform Update from google play store.

```
adb install -r foo.apk
```